# Rails transaction doesn't rollback on validation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, transactions

I have two models: user and company.  They both get created from one form and I'm using a transaction like this:

```
 User.transaction do

  @user.save!

  @company.user = @user
  @company.save!

  @user.reload
  @user.company = @company
  @user.save!

 flash[:notice] = "Thank you for your registration."
  redirect_to_index
end
```

The user gets saved to the database even when one of the company's validations fails.  I've tried adding explicit error handling of ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid but it didn't help.  I thought the validation would raise the error to rollback the transaction anyway.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Does it support transactions (MyISAM vs InnoDB)?

Comment: Ah, I think that's it.  Most  tables are innoDB, but there are some myisam.  Thanks

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481806/how-do-i-get-save-no-exclamation-point-semantics-in-an-activerecord-transaction

Answer (score 3):

attempting to save a new entry and revise an existing entry (based on the new entry) at the same time, ran into a similar problem.  Tried transaction with rescue failed validation, but settled on this instead:

```
if @new_entry.valid? && @existing_entry.valid?
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    @new_entry.save!
    @existing_entry.save!
  end
end
```

the code validates first.  it doesn't attempt to save unless both entries are valid.  transaction semantics guard against incomplete entry on other errors if the database supports it.  hope that's a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

You must use a database engine that supports ACID transactions.  For mysql that is INNODB.

```
show table status\G
```

If users or companies is *not* using InnoDB engine, you can change it w/ this command.

```
ALTER TABLE <table name> ENGINE INNODB;
```

the exception thrown from `@company.save!` *should trigger a ROLLBACK command to be sent to the database.  you can verify this in the console/logfile when running script/server with DEBUG log level.

Comment: Do not catch an ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid exception inside a transaction because the this exception invalidates the transaction on some databases like Postgres. Once the transaction has been invalidated you must restart it from the beginning for it to work correctly.

http://markdaggett.com/blog/2011/12/01/transactions-in-rails/

Answer (score 0):

You will have to consider these scenarios

1. Use a database system that supports transaction
2. Re-Factor that code for a more logical approach

As an example, if you only have a one-to-one relation, it can be handled in more optimized way

```
Company has_one User
User belongs_to Company
```

Now, in Company model

```
@company.user.build(user_attributes)
@company.save  # will save company as well as user
```

I have not tested it as an example. Just off my mind.
Have I understood the problem correctly?

Answer (score 0):

save() and destroy() are always under transaction (see http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.5/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html).

What I think you want to be doing is

```
  begin
    @company = Company.create!(params[:company])
    @user    = User.create!(params[:user]) { |user| user.company => @company }
  rescue => ex
    # ... handle your validation errors
  end
```

This would solve your problem as when company validations fail an exception will be raised and the User.create statement never executes.

Answer (score -3):

http://tempe.st/2007/05/transaction-in-rails/

I believe you must use a begin end block outside the transaction loop.

Comment: Not true. If you want to do something more than a simple rollback, you'll need a `begin`..`rescue`..`end` block, but an exception handler higher up the stack can just as easily handle it after the rollback is done. You can also let Rails handle it and show an error page.